# .net Core 3.1 WPF Switching Cleartype off?

Tags: wpf, text, .net-core, rendering, cleartype

In .NET Framework WPF there was an option to render Text in Display mode, which means beautiful pixels without Cleartype artifacts that you would get when randering with Ideal mode.

How can you render readable text with WPF in Core 3.1? There is no rendering option anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" is still there. But it was/is missing in the VS 2019 Property Window of the WPF editor. Adding it by hand works.